# How can I explain that a boy keeps coming in my home, without saying anything specific about the timing of when he comes?

Tags: deictic-verbs

> There is a boy whose name is Peter he keep coming  in my home frequently not regularly sometime he come after three day sometime come after one month.

So how can I translate such a sentence? and speaking time I don't want to put timing when he comes.  I want to give answer to someone without timing if someone asks about Peter. Then what is the correct option from the following ones?

> Peter **is coming** my home.
>   Peter **comes** my home.
>   Peter **coming** my home.

Please explain to me which of these sentences is correct.

Comment: Where is the first sentence taken from? ("There is a boy whose name is Peter he keep coming in my home frequently not regularly sometime he come after three day sometime come after one month."). Did **you** write it?

Comment: "Peter regularly/often/sometimes **visits** me at home."OR  "Peter often (etc) comes **to** my home"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mention that your friend Peter comes to your home frequently - then you have to say:

> "Peter comes to my home frequently"

In this way you don't mention the exact time/s, you just say that he comes to you frequently. You can change the adverb to: not often, rarely or infrequently, according to your need.

The form of "peter comes to my home" is a form of *[present simple tense](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-tense/)* that is used when talking about habits, customs and for repeated actions or events. In such case is better to express the frequency of the habit etc.

Your second sentence is:

> Peter **is coming** to my home.

It is a [present progressive tense](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_progressive.htm) and it's mainly used to talk about the moment. That's why if you say that "Peter is coming to you", it means that he is on the way to you **at the moment**.

Your third sentence is:

> Peter coming to my home.

It's incorrect sentence, because it's ungrammatical. The [auxiliary verb](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/auxiliaryverb.htm) [is], is missed here.

Comment: You need "**to** my home" in all cases.

Comment: Done. Even though personally I would not omit the preposition "to" in such sentences, I thought that it's not mistake to use it without it as well. Isn't it?

Comment: It might be used in AmE, but not BrE. You can, of course, say "Peter is coming home with me."